# Detailed changes view in Hudson CI

Tags: mercurial, hudson

Is there any way to get the details of the commit? At the moment when I go to changes I can see the following:

[image]

but I'd be great to be able to see the commit details (e.g redmine does it )

[image].

I use Mercurial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to activate another repository browser for this (e.g. hgweb):

[image]

Comment: Does it mean that I have to start hg serve somewhere and then point hgweb to that URL?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. We do the same with SVN/ViewVC which is also an external server.